# NGINX - IP:Port redirect browser location to sub.domain.com?

Tags: nginx

I am having an issue when directly inputting the ip address and port of my server into a browser, I want it to redirect to the subdomain address (i.e https://11.22.33.444 > https://www.example.com)

I'm currently running Swag (NGINX) in a docker container.

This is my NGINX config file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# redirect all traffic to https
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    #location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com;
    #}
}

# main server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name 11.22.33.444;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php$is_args$args =404;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess/.htpasswd files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start by trying to use the actual server name instead of `server_name _;` to make sure it's not catching all and getting predesence over the ip block.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I changed it to `server_name domain.com;` but makes no difference to redirecting the browsers location to `sub.domain.com`.

Comment: My thinking was that since the redirect is not working, `11.22.33.444` is probably matched by `# main server block` instead of the intended redirect block due to `default_server` and the servername (common practice to create a catch-all block).

Comment: Another ide is that you have some conflicting block in one of your `*.subdomain.conf` files.

Comment: Maybe to simplify the issue, I've cut back the config (as below).

Case 1.
Visiting `http://11.22.33.444` correctly redirects the browser to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Case 2 (fails). Visting `https://11.22.33.444` gives me a _Your connection is not private_ in the browser.